# MATLAB non-linear regression using cost function

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

Currently, I am trying to figure out how to solve a non-linear system using a model. The model is:

```
m2(x) = a*x + 2*exp(b*x)
```

I have to solve for a and b using the data:

```
x = [0.00,0.25,0.50,0.75,1.00];
y = [2.10,3.70,6.26,10.03,16.31];
```

Using that I solve the following cost function:

```
(a,b) = sum(y(i) - m2(x(i))^2
```

I have been trying for a while now and I can't figure out how to extract a and b from m2(x(i)). fsolve has not worked for me, I have also tried the routine solve function. I am not looking for an answer but I am looking for a direction to take as I am at a complete roadblock.

Edit: The model captures the dependence of y on the independent variable x
I ran this function to get the 5 equations.

```
function [f] = func(x,y)
    syms a b
    f = a*x + 2 * exp(b*x) == y;
end
```

With the driver:

```
for i = 1:5
    f(i) = func(x(i),y(i));
end
disp(f');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your unknowns are `a,b` so I parametrized them as `w` in the model, instead of what you did. I used `lsqnonlin` and solved as follows:

```
x = [0.00,0.25,0.50,0.75,1.00];
y = [2.10,3.70,6.26,10.03,16.31];
m2 = @(w) w(1)*x + 2*exp(w(2)*x);


cost_func = @(w) m2(w)-y; 
v = lsqnonlin(cost_func,[1 1]); % normal least squares
plot(x,y,'x',x,m2(v));
```

Comment: Thank you, two quick questions, why did you an absolute value, and how do I extract the a and b values? I need to compute the gradient ∇Φ = "∂Φ/∂a2/∂Φ/∂b2" or am I able to use v to calculate the gradient?

Comment: read the documentation on how to use `lsqnonlin`. The abs value, or  abs(  )^2  is not needed for the cost function here (but you can use it if you want), The a,b are the two numbers that the output `v` has, as it is plotted as well a line below as input to `m2`

Comment: as for the gradient , what is phi ?

Comment: Yes, I just read it and am looking more into it. As for Phi is is Phi(a,b) so I guess it makes sense that I can just use v for the gradient. I have it currently as: F = gradient(m2(v));